# Access : Trouble with calculating in new query (data type mismatch in criteria expression)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016, sqldatatypes

I'm new on Access and I'm struggling to do something that looks easy. I need your help

In a table i have a field (`PERMITTIVITY`) in a number (double) data type.
I would like to create a new field (directly in the table or in a new query) with this expression : `Log([PERMITTIVITY])*0,092376679+0,003073477`

And i would like to be able to make `Avg` (grouped by time and place) with the `Total` row in the query. But that lead me to errors like "data type mismatch in criteria expression", "type mismatch"

If it can help, here is the SQL code of the query

```
SELECT ZONE.COMPOSITION, SENSOR_ZONE.ZONE, SENSOR_ZONE.TREATMENT, SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.MEASURE, SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.DATES, Avg(SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.VALUE_RAW) AS AvgOfVALUE_RAW, Avg(SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.VALUE_RAW_FILTERED) AS AvgOfVALUE_RAW_FILTERED, Avg(SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.PERMITTIVITY) AS AvgOfPERMITTIVITY, Avg(SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.WATER_CONTENT_Jonard) AS AvgOfWATER_CONTENT_Jonard, Avg(SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.WATER_CONTENT_Jacobsen) AS AvgOfWATER_CONTENT_Jacobsen, **Avg(Log([PERMITTIVITY])*0.092376679+0.003073477) AS WATER_CONTENT_GuiTil**, First(SENSOR.SENSOR) AS FirstOfSENSOR, Avg(METEO.TempAir) AS AvgOfTempAir, Avg(METEO.TempForest) AS AvgOfTempForest, Avg(METEO.Radiation) AS AvgOfRadiation, Avg(METEO.WindDir) AS AvgOfWindDir, Avg(METEO.RelHum) AS AvgOfRelHum, Avg(METEO.TempSoil) AS AvgOfTempSoil, Sum(METEO.Rain) AS SumOfRain, Avg(METEO.WindSpeed) AS AvgOfWindSpeed

FROM 
[ZONE] INNER JOIN ((SENSOR_ZONE INNER JOIN SENSOR ON (SENSOR_ZONE.N_SENSOR = SENSOR.N_SENSOR) AND (SENSOR_ZONE.MEASURE = SENSOR.MEASURE)) INNER JOIN (METEO INNER JOIN SOIL_WATER_CONTENT ON (METEO.Years = SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.Years) AND (METEO.Months = SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.Months) AND (METEO.Days = SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.Days) AND (METEO.Hours = SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.Hourss)) ON (SENSOR.N_SENSOR = SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.N_SENSOR) AND (SENSOR.MEASURE = SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.MEASURE)) ON (ZONE.TREATMENT = SENSOR_ZONE.TREATMENT) AND (ZONE.ZONE = SENSOR_ZONE.ZONE)

GROUP BY 
ZONE.COMPOSITION, SENSOR_ZONE.ZONE, SENSOR_ZONE.TREATMENT, SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.MEASURE, SOIL_WATER_CONTENT.DATES;
```

I have tried :

- to add a new calculated field in my table but didn't succeed to transform it into a number data type to be able to use it -> "type mismatch"
- to add a new field in the query with the expression "WATER_CONTENT_GuiTil: Avg(Log([PERMITTIVITY])*0,092376679+0,003073477)" but the Avg part is not working -> "data type mismatch in criteria expression"
- to write the expression "Log([PERMITTIVITY])*0,092376679+0,003073477" in the criteria row -> "not part of an aggregate function"

Comment: Please edit question to provide sample data as formatted text table(s). Your expression works for me with my data.

Comment: You need to create field with the Log() expression then select AVG in the Total row.

Comment: I dont know how to provide sample data in a formatted text table but the `PERMITTIVITY` field is filled with 300 000 numbers like 20,6751921832182

"You need to create field with the Log() expression then select AVG in the Total row." That is what i tried in the second bullet point

Comment: Review https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support and https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables.

Comment: Don't know what else to say. Expression works for me. You are using non-U.S. decimal. Does the multiplication with those numbers work in a non-aggregate query?